# In join want to get not matched records

Tags: linq, entity-framework, join

Work on DF 4 vs 2010.Face problem on  join  on SalSalesOrderDetail with  SalSalesOrderFinancial table.

[image]

In  SalSalesOrderFinancial one record have SalesOrderDetailID=null. Want to get those records whose SalesOrderDetailID is not present in SalSalesOrderFinancial.

To get desired out put write bellow linq syntax,it’s working .Looking for better join syntax .Is there any way to get desired in one join.

```
      var tempBDwithSODetail = (from p in this.Context.SalSalesOrderFinancials
                                          where p.SalesOrderDetailID != null
                                          select p.SalesOrderDetailID).AsEnumerable();

                var tempBDwithOutSODetail = (from p in this.Context.SalSalesOrderFinancials where p.SalesOrderDetailID == null select p).AsEnumerable();
                var querySOD = (this.Context.SalSalesOrderDetails.Where(item => !tempBDwithSODetail.Contains(item.SalesOrderDetailID))).AsEnumerable();

var tempBDetail = (from p in querySOD
                  join q in tempBDwithOutSODetail on p.SalesOrderID equals q.SalesOrderID
                                   where q.SalesOrderDetailID == null
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       q.SalesOrderID,
                                       p.SalesOrderDetailID,
                                       q.CurrencyID,
                                       q.BillingPolicyID,
                                       q.BillTypeID,
                                       q.BillingTypeID
                                   }).AsEnumerable();
```

If have any query please ask.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

if i got you, you just need to simple left join between `SalSalesOrderDetail` and `SalSalesOrderFinancial`...

```
var query = (from u in this.Context.SalSalesOrderDetail
             join t in this.Context.SalSalesOrderFinancials 
                 on u.SalesOrderDetailID equals t.SalesOrderDetailID into JoinedList
             from t in JoinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 SalSalesOrderDetail = t,
                 SalSalesOrderFinancials = u
             })
             .Where(u => u.SalSalesOrderFinancials == null)
             .ToList();
```